# Como dizer ao compilador que toda ObservableList<O> que eu passar como argumento irá conter determinado método?

Tags: java, javafx, genéricos

Tenho o seguinte método para fazer pesquisa:

```
public class Pesquisa {
private static <O> ObservableList<O> pesquisarPorNome(ObservableList<O> listaObservavel, String pesquisa) {
    ObservableList<O> novaLista = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for(int x = 0; x<listaObservavel.size(); x++) {
        if(listaObservavel.get(x).getNome().toLowerCase().contains(pesquisa.toLowerCase()));
        novaLista.add(listaObservavel.get(x));
    }
    return novaLista;
}
```

Não quero escrever esse método em todas as classes, por isso criei esse método separado que todas as classes que contém o método `getNome()` irão usar. Generalizei tudo e ta beleza, mas da erro justamente no método `getNome()` dizendo que não reconhece esse método.

Como eu posso dizer ao compilador que toda `ObservableList` que eu passarei como argumento irá conter esse método?

Lembrando que passarei `ObservableLists` de várias classes diferentes, mas elas sempre conterão um `getNome()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deve fazer uma restrição ao que pode usar como parâmetro:

```
private static <O extends AlgumTipo>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/GenericExtends.java).

onde `AlgumTipo` pode ser uma classe, interface ou outro tipo que em seu contrato tenha o método `getNome()`, portanto o compilador só aceitará um tipo que herda deste tipo e como ele sabe que o objeto tem esse método ele deixa passar.

Obviamente ele não deixa compilar se tentar passar um objeto de um tipo que não seja o especificado ou derivado dele. Não basta ter o método, tem que ser um tipo derivado do escrito em `extends`, ou ele próprio se for possível.

Então acredito que precise criar esse tipo geral. Não existe generalização sem um ascendente comum.

Isto chama-se *bounded type parameter*, ou seja, é um parâmetro de tipo restrito ao que funcionará neste contexto.

Se não puder fazer este tipo e tudo que quer passar para este método `pesquisarPorNome()` puder ter essa característica então não tem solução.

Eu dei a resposta mais específica que pude dentro do que foi postado na pergunta.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela reposta, fiz uma interface Pesquisavel, deu tudo certo no inicio, mas na hora que fui chamar o método pesquisaPorNome(ObservableList<Pesquisavel> listaObservavel, String pesquisa) passando como argumento Pesquisa.pesquisar(mainApp.getGruposData(), pesquisaTextField.getText())
Onde o getGruposData() retorna uma Observable List de Grupos, que é uma classe que implementa a interface Pesquisavel, deu tudo certo no resto, só nessa chamada de erro que está dando errado, o eclipse acusa que o método recebe um Pesquisavel, não um Grupo,sendo que Grupo implementa Pesquisavel,Porque?

Comment: Tá muito confuso para responder e é outra pergunta.